# CRM 2011 - Auditing of "Two Options" Fields on Create Operation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am encountering a problem with the **Two Options fields**, having the **Auditing option enabled** in CRM 2011.

Since the CRM Two Options fields have a **default value No/Yes** by default, related audit records are always created for these fields on entity Create, when Auditing is enabled.

These field audits that include the default Boolean value (false/true), are in fact useless for the user, seeing that this initial unchanged value should be considered as ***Null***. So, the audits should not be created and shown to the user in this case, especially when there are numerous Boolean fields and very frequent Create operations on the entity.

I could set the default value of the Two Options field *twoOptionsField* to ***null*** instead of ***false*** or ***true***, by doing this on the form Load:

```javascript
var twoOptionsField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("twoOptionsField");
twoOptionsField.setValue(null); // set the value to null
twoOptionsField.setSubmitMode("always"); // store the null value
```

But this will automatically add the field audit with an empty value on Create.

Is there any efficient way we could avoid the audit records for initial "null"/default valued Two Options fields, having Auditing enabled, on entity Create?

Comment: Would it work to alter the setting using a plugin that reacts to *Create* message? (Not quite sure but it's an idea.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will check if anything could work with a plugin reacting to Create message (Pre-operation), and will update you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any setting to set that. One strategy you can have is in pre create\update of a entity check the value of that field and if is null you [disable the audit feature](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Change-Audit-Setting-of-attributes-of-an-Entity-in-CRM-2011-1379.php) for that field and if is not null enable the audit. The audit can be applied to organization\entity and attribute. I don't try this is just a ideia :D

Comment: Thank you. I will check the plugin suggestion soon. But I think disabling the audit feature in the code will not be a good solution:

Consider _User 1_ creates a new record of the Entity with _null Boolean Field_, the Audit log will be disabled (could be temporarily) in the code and the field will not be audited; this is okay. And at the same time, _User 2_ creates a new record of the Entity with _modified Boolean Field_. The audit here should be created for User 2. But in this case, the Audit log is just disabled, so the audit record will not be inserted, and this is wrong.

Comment: Ok, i don't think in that situation. But if you disabled the audit in pre and active in post event i think it should run well, you gonna have milliseconds of difference, but it's a risk, if i have a better solution i put here.